# Custom output PsObject

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

this is my code

```
$Return = New-Object PSObject

Add-Member -InputObject $Return -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Source -Value "Test1"
Add-Member -InputObject $Return -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileMQ -Value "Test2"
Add-Member -InputObject $Return -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Listener -Value "Test3"
```

I want to output $Return like this :

```
Source : Test1 | FileMQ : Test2 | Listener : Test3
```

I know I can achieve like this :

```
"Source : $($return.Source) | FileMQ : $($return.FileMQ) | Listener : $($return.Listener)"
```

But I'm sure there is more automatic and efficient way...because If I have too many members it will be difficult. Can anyone help me?

I'm using Powershell V4.

Thanks

Comment: `$Return|%{($_.PSObject.Properties|%{'{0} : {1}'-f$_.Name,$_.Value})-join' | '}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the hidden `psobject` memberset property to enumerate all the properties of your object and construct the string like so:

```
($Return.psobject.Properties |% { '{0} : {1}' -f $_.Name,$_.Value }) -join ' | '
```